# How to count a cell which is green in color in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api, google-sheets-macros

I have a case where i need to count if a cell has color of "green" in google sheet.
I tried few adons but they didn't work. I am looking for a solution via a script or a formula.

I have around 4 green values as shown in the attachment below

[image]

Tried this but it returns zero

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //define here range of interest
  var range = sheet.getRange("BG4:BO");
  var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
  var counter = 0;
  var green = "00ff00"
  for (var i = 0; i < backgrounds.length; i++){
    if(backgrounds[i]== "#00ff00")
      counter++;
  }
  Logger.log(counter); 
  sheet.getRange(3, 59).setValue(counter);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to count how many cells are green, or do you want to sum the values contained in the green cells?

Comment: count how many values are in green

Comment: @ziganotschka what can be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### You can count the green cells with Google Apps Script using the method [getBackgrounds()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getbackgrounds)

Sample:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  //define here range of interest
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:A10");
  var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
  var counter = 0;
  var green = "#00ff00";
  for (var i = 0; i < backgrounds.length; i++){
    if(backgrounds[i]== green)
      counter++;
  }
  Logger.log(counter);  
}
```

### UPDATE

If you want to run the function on more than one column, you need to convert the 2D backgrounds array into a 1D one in order to run the function above. This can be accomplished with [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat). So:

```
...
var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
backgrounds = backgrounds.flat();
var counter = 0;
...
```

Comment: I see, this is because you have a multiple column range, see my updated answer.